# missing images and home page when moving laravel 5.2 project to live server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

images works fine  in localhost as src="/lr/public/bootstrap/images/photo.jpg"
but don't work on live server

error messages on live server is failed 404 not found www.mysite.com/lr/public/bootstrap/images/photo.com

note : when i remove /lr/public images works on live server

my cpanel root directory is /home/ad

in /home/ad >>
i have folder'lr' that containe my project and i deleted folder public in it

in public_html >> 
i have contents of folder public >> bootstrap - uploads - index.php ..... etc

Comment: I think that may be wrong configuration on Apache or Nginx.

Comment: how can i solve the problem

Comment: It's better to show your nginx or apache config file.

Comment: sorry do you mean web.config in  cpanel or  how can i find it

Comment: Are you using dedicated server or sharing server like cpanel login?

Comment: i used sharing server cpanel

Comment: Check this out [here](http://laravel.io/forum/03-06-2015-how-to-setup-laravel-5-in-shared-hosting)

Comment: i checked this solution before but dont work for me

Comment: do you have a '/' route in your route files? like this: 

Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});

Comment: no . i dont have / route like Route::get('/', function () { return 'Hello World'; });  -- instead of  i have /home to home page

Comment: Looks like a clean install would be better. Backup your files, remove everything and put a Laravel installation on again. Follow those errors and you'll be fine. Once done put everything back on one by one and see what goes wrong (if anything).

Comment: thanks , thomas  , szebasztian . the problem is / route missing in my routes.php when i add / route the project works fine . but image still missing. please any help about missing images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you didn't link your images correctly.

I believe the link should be:
www.mysite.com/bootstrap/images/photo.jpg

not: 
www.mysite.com/lr/public/bootstrap/images/photo.com

Use: `asset('bootstrap/images/photo.jpg')` for linking files from your public folder.

Blade example. `<img src="{{ asset('bootstrap/images/photo.jpg') }}">`

Make sure 'photo.jpg' exists in 'public/bootstrap/images/' directory

Comment: thanks kabelo for your replay . but in my bootstrap.min.css : body{background-image: url('/lr/public/bootstrap/images/x.jpg');}    how can solve this in live server

Comment: Try an absolute path to the image `body{background-image: url('lr/public/bootstrap/images/x.jpg');}`

Comment: thanks kabelo it works fine when remove /lr/public and keep/bootstrap on live server

Comment: Or this `body{background-image: url('bootstrap/images/x.jpg');}` if your domain.com points to your app's public folder

Comment: Okay great mohamed!